# In JavaScript or jQuery, how to convert ontouchmove event into a basic click event on target

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, touch

I am running my web app on Chromium on a touch device. It's an industry control panel, not a consumer tablet.

I have a problem when the user means to click (tap) on a button, but their finger moves a little, thus causing the 'ontouchmove' event to fire. I other words, the device reads it as a swipe instead of a click.

When this happens, the click event is not fired, so nothing happens, even though the button's hover is triggered. So, the user sees that their touch was registered (button changes color), but is then frustrated by the fact that nothing happens.

I'm hoping I can put something in index.html that globally converts these swipes into standard old-fashioned clicks.

```
document.ontouchmove = function() {
  // get target of this event
  // fire the click event of that target
}
```

Is this even possible? I have jQuery installed. Is something like hammerjs needed? I'd like to get by with plain old JavaScript, if possible.

Thanks

Comment: It's little dirty I think but you can fired your element click event inside your element ontouchmove event. It's what you looking for ?

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure but you can try it :

```
document.on("touchmove", function(e) {
  $(e.target).trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: @JerryHuckins Well, can you accept my answer please :)